# NetBeans 8.2 adding new project to my SVN subversion repository

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm running NetBeans 8.2.  I created a simple new Java application and I want to commit this new project to my SVN subversion repository.  I cannot see any way to do this.  After the new project, it looks like NetBeans thinks the new project is already connected somewhere.  I can to to Team > commit, and when I do that the commit dialog box that appears shows the project's file system location as the Repository Path.  I can't find any way to specify the SVN repository I want to commit the new project to for the first time.  So thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of my problem.  Somehow, I got an .svn directory inside of the directory where I create all of my projects.  I deleted that .svn directory and now NetBeans recognizes the new project as not being connected to source control, so I have the option to import it into SVN now.